# What R code should be used to learn if there is a significant difference between two predictor variables in the way they affect a response variable?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I am trying to learn if Extraversion affects how people follow COVID-19 guidelines when stratified by male/female gender.

The data is set up so Extraversion is the predictor variable, guideline compliance is the response variable, and the data are stratified by gender.

I tried to create two models for each gender and then put them through an ANOVA (this is what ChatGPT recommended). But, R didn't like that saying "models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset".

I think the issue is that there are way more females than males in the sample. Also, I would like to use another method to find a significant difference between the two model's results because each model follows the Poisson distribution and ANOVA only likes normal distributions.

````
  dplyr::filter(Q34 == "Male")

dataFemale <- data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Q34 == "Female")

poisson_male <- glm(CDC ~ Extraversion, data=dataMale, family=poisson())

poisson_female <- glm(CDC ~ Extraversion, data=dataFemale, family=poisson())

anova(poisson_male, poisson_female, test="Chisq")
```
````

Comment: Let's shift focus from what R code you should be using to what statistical model you might best employ. I would like to know much more about guideline complicance is (e.g. plots of distribution). I can't see a case for two models: guideline compliance is, it seems, possibly a result of extraversion and male/female. But are these data on separate individuals or panel data?

Comment: Those who live by ChatGP3 are destined to get advice of unpredictable quality.

Comment: I don't use R routinely and remember almost nothing about it, but I wonder whether the ANOVA makes any sense here.

Comment: When did ChatGP3 become statistical guru?!

Comment: What are you trying to find out? If you are interested in whether Extraversion-compliance relation is different for men and women, a typical way to investigate this is one model with Extraversion, gender and their interaction as predictors.

Answer (score 2):

You should fit a single model that includes an interaction between Extraversion and Gender in it and test whether there is evidence for the presence of the interaction. The model should look like the following:

```r
glm(CDC ~ Extraversion + Gender + Extraversion:Gender,
    data=data, family=poisson())
```

The test for the coefficient on `Extraversion:Gender` tells you whether the relationship between `Extraversion` and `CDC` depends on (i.e., varies across levels of) `Gender`.

(To make the analysis more robust to violations of certain technical assumptions, I would change `poisson()` to `quasipoisson()` and use a robust standard error.)

Do not rely on ChatGPT to answer questions about statistics. It doesn't know what it's talking about (literally).